# Convert unicode byte arrary to a binary byte arrary

Tags: vb.net

I have a byte() array full of Unicode data. I need to convert this byte array to binary data.

The original data was binary data, but data was saved as Unicode, and thus these data structures are now all 2 times as large as they need to be.

Can I convert from a byte array of one type to another byte array, or is looping required to skip every other byte?

Edit:

Comments asked for more info

The original byte array is Unicode UTF32 looks to be the format.

The output byte array needs to remove that extra encoding.

So, assuming this, then EndianUnicode as bytes to toss out the extra data works quite well

This seems to work:

```
 b2 = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes
            (System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString(b))
```

Of course it not clear as to why the resulting array is not EXACTLY 1/2 in size but the above does seem to work.

Edit2:
Ok, as noted, the question was not ONLY how to convert, but was btye arrary to btye array. Further more, the array was indeed Unicode, but the original binary byte array was based on the users local code page (English).

So the CORRECT conversion I required was this:

```
 b2 = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes
            (System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(b))
```

However, the above converts from a byte arrary to a string, and then back to a byte array. My question was STILL how to do this from byte arrary to byte array. Turns out you can do this, and this is how:

```
Dim b() As Byte
b = reader(0)   ' the array is filled with Unicode (air code)
Dim b2() As Byte
' convert byte array - not have to convert to strings

Dim cFrom As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
Dim cto As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default

b2 = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(cFrom, cto, b)
```

As noted, above is byte() array to byte() array as per my original question. 
Note that "default" in above is of course the default code page (in my case a computer running English version of windows).

Comment: Full of Unicode? UTF-32? Or maybe UTF-16 which would fit your describtion `and thus these data structures are now all 2 times as large as they need to be.`? In which format do you want it to be? UTF-8? ASCII? Binary-Data doesn't describe any format at all.

Comment: Ok, well, the issue was that some binary data was converted during a process to uni code. It doubled the resulting data. So, see my above comments - it is a "guess" that a process converted this data - we did not want this to occur. So far, it looks like the accident conversion is UTF-32. The above posted code works, but resulting data is not 1/2, but the resulting data (pdf files) do seem to be ok after the above converting.

Comment: [Encoding.Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.convert?view=netframework-4.7.2). `UTF-32`? Hmm. Who uses `UTF-32`? In Windows it's usually `UTF-16` (strings) and `UTF-8` or Local Encoding (files and WebClient strings). If the resulting bytes length is not exaclty doubled, if might be `UTF-8`: the lower CodePoints use just 1 byte.

Comment: I have added to my question. Checking this out, the data came from a binary byte array (and a windows code page of English). When converted, the end result was Unicode. (so it was not UTF32). To get the byte array back, then converting from Unicode back to the original windows code page (English) restored the data to its original format (and half the size). As noted, if the conversion of the byte streams to Unicode did not occur in the first place, then all would be well. However, my question ALSO asked how to convert the byte array  (not convert to strings). I provided an answer to that ?